# Elementary Set Theory: Proof of Distributive Property

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm new to proofs.  While working through a finite math book, I've been asked to prove the distributive properties of set operations.  I'll use the distributive property of union over intersection as the example for my question.

**Prove that A ∪ (B ∩ C) = (A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C).**

The proofs I see for this property aim to show, in two steps, that each side is a subset of the other side.  For example, the first step usually looks something like this:

1. Let *x* ∈ A ∪ (B ∩ C). If *x* ∈ A ∪ (B ∩ C) then *x* is either in A or in (B and C).
2. *x* ∈ A or *x* ∈ (B and C)
3. *x* ∈ A or {*x* ∈ B and *x* ∈ C}
4. {*x* ∈ A or *x* ∈ B} and {*x* ∈ A or *x* ∈ C}
5. *x* ∈ (A or B) and *x* ∈ (A or C)
6. *x* ∈ (A ∪ B) ∩ *x* ∈ (A ∩ C)
7. *x* ∈ (A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C)
8. *x* ∈ A ∪ (B ∩ C) => *x* ∈ (A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C)
9. Therefore, A ∪ (B ∩ C) ⊂ (A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C)

Then the second step would do something similar to show that (A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C) ⊂ A ∪ (B ∩ C).

My question in this--**In jumping from lines 3 to 4, aren't we relying on the very property we're trying to prove?**  If so, how is that considered as proof?

I don't have trouble following the steps, and I don't doubt that the property is valid.  But as a newcomer to proofs I'm confused because it looks (to me) like we're using the property to prove itself.  To my non-mathematician mind, drawing a couple of Venn diagrams provides a more intuitive "proof" than manipulating these equations.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: As mentioned above, you use one law in logic to prove a (visually very similar) law in set theory. They are technically distinct, although you still need to prove that the step from 3 to 4 is valid, either by proving it yourself or quoting a theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jumping from $3$ to $4$ needs to be justified.

At $3$ you have $x \in A$ or $(x \in B \;\text{and} \; x \in C).$

Then we form two cases. One in which we see what happens when $x \in A$ and second in which $x \in B \cap C$.

**Case 1): $x \in A$ -**

Since $A \subseteq A \cup B$ and $A \subseteq A \cup C$,

$x \in A \implies x \in A \cup B$ and $x \in A \implies x \in A \cup C$. Thus $x \in A \cup B$ and $x \in A \cup C$. That is $x \in (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C).$

**Case 2):$x \in B \cap C$ -**

Since $x \in B$ and $x \in C$, we have $x \in A \cup B$ and $x \in A \cup C$. $(\because B \subseteq A \cup B, C \subseteq A \cup C).$

Thus $x \in (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$ in this case too.

Oops we jumped to $7$ directly. :P

Answer (score 2):

From lines 3 to 4 you are using the property $\text{A or (B and C)} \Leftrightarrow  \text{(A or B) and (A or C)}$ which is not related to the properties of the $\in$ operator. This property can be proved using truth tables, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Let's prove that $(A\cup B)\cap C = (A\cup C)\cap(B\cup C)$.

Firstly, let $x \in (A\cup C)\cap(B\cup C)$, then $x \in A\cup C$ and $x \in B\cup C$.

Secondly, there may be two options:

1. $x \in C$, and therefore $x \in (A\cap B)\cup C$.
2. $x \notin C$. Then $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. So $x \in A\cap B$, and therefore $x \in (A\cap B)\cup C$.

Finally, $x \in (A\cap B)\cup C$ in both options, and $x \in (A\cup C)\cap (B\cup C)$ is given. Therefore, $(A\cap B)\cup C = (A\cup C)\cap(B\cup C)$.